# Formatting sections, subsections... trouble titlesec

Tags: titlesec, section-titles

I have a problem at the moment to edit subsections and else with titlesec, I've read the documentation (and probably misunderstand it), done few attempts, but no success. I attached the image with that I wish to obtain,[image] the code of my MWE,

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec,calc}
\usepackage{changepage}

\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{%
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
    \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
  }%
  \item[]}{\end{list}}

\begin{document}

\section{X}
%Otra subsección
\titleformat{\subsection}[wrap]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{.5em}{}\titlespacing{\subsection}{12pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}
\subsection{Mí titulo es largo y complicado}
Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau Miau 

\vspace*{0.5cm}

\subsection{Mí titulo es largo y complicado 2}
\begin{changemargin}{120pt}{0pt}
Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto 
\end{changemargin}


\titleformat{\subsection}[leftmargin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{-1em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{-10pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}
\subsection{Mí titulo es largo y complicado 2}

\begin{changemargin}{40pt}{0pt}
Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto 
\end{changemargin} 

\end{document}
```

and another image that I have gotten so far [image].

I'd like to put the section and its number inside in a `minipage` but I couldn't do it and I don't know if it is the best idea. In the second result I used a new environment but in the work of interest doesn't look good and is not perfectly aligned in the horizontal with the section name as the first result. Is there any way to do it with new enviroments or directly with `margin` option of titlesec.

According to the documentation `\titlespacing*{〈command〉}{〈left〉}{〈before-sep〉}{〈after-sep〉}[〈right-sep〉` but I'd like be capable to move the title in the margin option, as a hole thing (as a figure with adjustbox), not only the separations. I hope having explain myself better.

Anyone can help me, give a clue, or something else, please? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Which layout are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: The first @Bernard

Comment: Well, your code does it. I don't understand your problem?

Comment: I'd rather like do it without defining a new enviroment. I'll modify my question. Thanks @Bernard

Comment: What don't you stick  to the first solution? It works fine for me. Is it lacking something? The margin style will have problems unless you have very wide margins.

Comment: I have a very wide margins actually because I should reproduce a very specific format.